# Problem with dynamic URL rewrite with .htaccess

Tags: php, apache, .htaccess, url-rewriting

I had spend last few hours to get static URL from dynamic URL with .htaccess
If I get wanted URL I also get 404 error.

Dynamic URL is `EN/section.php?lang=$1&url=$2` I had wrote `^(.*)/(.*)$` and it doesn't work. This work well with some prefix like `^language-(.*)/(.*)$` and then I get URL like  domain/language-en/some-section and it works but it is not wanted URL

```
RewriteRule ^(.*)/(.*)$ EN/section.php?lang=$1&url=$2 [L]
```

I expect URL like domain/en/some-section not URL like domain/language-en/some-section.

Comment: (.) is matching any single character.
(.*) matches one or more characters.

Answer (score 0):

Solved!!!

```
RewriteRule ^/?([a-z]+)/(.*)$ EN/section.php?lang=$1&url=$2 [L]
```

and

```
RewriteCond ${REQUEST_URI} ^.+$
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} \.(gif|jpe?g|png|js|css|swf|php|ico|txt|pdf|xml)$ [OR]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -f [OR]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -d [OR]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -l
RewriteRule ^ - [L]
```

because after rewrite URL I had lost all images, CSS, javascript, etc...